# Is there a way to create something likea draggable menu in wearable device in Android?

Tags: android-layout, draggable, android-wear-2.0

I was wondering if it is possible to create something like a menu that I can drag either by the side or from above on a wearable device. But I don't want it to affect the activity I have. You know like on a smart phone and you drag down the menu with some settings like brightness, rotation, etc...

To elaborate, I have a timer with a progress bar, but my activity would be overcrowded if I added any other stuff. So I want something to drag from the top of the screen to check on something, then drag again to return to my view that has the timer and progress bar. I basically have an activity where I make some selections, I wanted my selections to appear in that draggable menu thing to check to see my selections displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two drawer components for the type of behavior that you describe. Which one is better depends on the specifics of your implementation. The documentation for Navigation Drawer and Action Drawer can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions).